# Is there a way to have a variable be `Handles Rdb1.Move, Rdb2.Move` for a sub

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to visual studio 2017. I want to have a variable that acts as a part of the code for a sub so instead of writing the whole thing I want to just put the variable.

I'm making a menu for a school project. I haven't really tried anything because I don't know how the code works.

`Private Sub ckb1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ckb1.CheckedChanged, rdbSuper.CheckedChanged, rdbPong.CheckedChanged`

How do I make the `rdbSuper.CheckedChanged, rdbPong.CheckedChanged` into just a variable so I can just put that after the Handles?

Comment: You can't. That's not how a `Handles` clause works.

Comment: I'm wondering what exactly you think you would achieve by doing that.  If we know what you're aim is then we may be able to provide some advice as to how might achieve it, in part or in whole, or explain why the aim makes no sense.

Comment: Also, you may not be aware that you can use the Properties window in the designer to manage event handler.  If you select the `CheckBox` and both `RadioButtons` in the designer, open the Properties window and click the Events button, you can then double-click the `CheckedChanged` event to create a handler or select an existing handler from the drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `Sub` for each `CheckedChanged`-Event with the same code, you can create one `Sub` and bind that function to the events with [`AddHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement):

```
Sub FunctionForEventCheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Your code for the CheckedChanged-Event.
End Sub

'bind the events with the FunctionForEventCheckedChanged function.
AddHandler rdbSuper.CheckedChanged, AddressOf FunctionForEventCheckedChanged
AddHandler rdbPong.CheckedChanged, AddressOf FunctionForEventCheckedChanged
```

You can also check for a specific checkbox inside the `FunctionForEventCheckedChanged` function with `sender`. So you can also create some code for specific checkboxes.

**How this can help you?**

It looks like you want to assign one function to multiple events. Since you can't group the events in a variable to use this variable on `Handles` you can do something like the following (based on the above explanation):

```
Dim arrCheckBoxes() As Control = {rdbSuper, ckb1}

For Each ctrlCheckBox As Control In arrCheckBoxes
    AddHandler ctrlCheckBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf FunctionForEventCheckedChanged
Next
```

Comment: While you're not wrong, I'm not really sure how that helps the OP in this case.